# How to best avoid memoryleaks when using UnityActions or C# Actions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, delegates

Ok, I am working with public static UnityActions for event driven multi delegate execution and I want to avoid memory leaks. I am worried that I miss removing a registered delegate. So I came up with the following construct:
Immediately when registering for an event I also register the command for unregistering to a separate action that I can execute at the end of the program like so:

```
// first establish a delegate to collect everything we need to de-register later OnDestroy
private delegate void Dreg();
private Dreg dreg;

// register for the event and create an entry in the de-register list 
//for later execution:
            MyEvents.SomeEvent += HandleSomeEvent;
            dreg += () => { MyEvents.SomeEvent -= HandleSomeEvent; };
```

At the end of the application I just need to invoke "dreg" to clear all registrations. This si working fine so far.

My question is: Can I wrap these two statements more elegantly into a function so that I just have to issue one statement instead of two? I have tried but I fail in the assignments.
My experiment looked something like this:

```
public static void RegisterForEvent(UnityAction _eventToRegisterFor, UnityAction _thingToAdd)
{
    _eventToRegisterFor += _thingToAdd;
    dreg += () => _eventToRegisterFor -= _delegateToAdd;
}
...
...Register(MyEvents.SomeEvent,HandleSomeEvent);// using this to register

...
...dreg.invoke;//near the end of the application to de-register everything
```

This does not seem to be possible.
My problem seems to be that I don't quite understand, what type "thingToAdd" actually is that I am assigning to MyEvents.SomeEvent? Is that a delegate? Is it a string that is resolved at runtime? is it a function??
I tried to work with C# Actions as well but did not succeed with that either.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated! Many thx before hand :-)

Comment: How is running something at the end of the application supposed to help with a memory leak?

Comment: `what type "thingToAdd" actually is that I am assigning to MyEvents.SomeEvent` you haven't shown us the code where you actually declare that event so -> We can't say what type it has

Comment: `This does not seem to be possible.` .. I don't see why it shouldn't .. what brings you to this conclusion?

Comment: @Ruzihm:  many thx for looking at this! :-)  I've read several articles on how the GC cannot free the memory if you keep any reference, naming multicast delegates explicitly. So from my limited understanding I want to make sure I de-register everything.

Comment: @derHugo: also many thx for trying to help. :-) You pointed me in the right direction by notimng that it should be possible and also wanting to look at the definition of the handler. As it turns out I had a mismatch in the number of parameters between the handler defintion and the delegate assignment. After fixing that it is working now. :-D

Comment: @Rachmaninow when a C# application is closed, all memory that the operating system reserved for that application is freed. No work needs to be done in the C# code for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I solved this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
public static void RegisterForEvent(UnityAction _eventToRegisterFor, UnityAction _handlerToAdd)
{
    _eventToRegisterFor += _handlerToAdd;
    dreg += () => _eventToRegisterFor -= _handlerToAdd;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//...the two lines above could be replaced with this one line call...

RegisterForEvent(MyEvents.SomeEvent,HandlerForSomeEvent);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//...and at the end the invokation of "dreg" will clear the event delegates
private void OnDestroy()
{
    dreg.invoke;//near the end of the application to de-register everything
}
```